# Props in styled-component component have no typing

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

I'm using react-native + typescript + styled-component (with all @types/* installed) but props still have no typing inside a "component"

What can be wrong?

I expect props to be `props: MainThemeInterface` or `props: { mode: string }`.

```
// button.component.ts
import { FC } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

interface ButtonComponentProps {
  title: string;
  onPress: (event: GestureResponderEvent) => void;
}

const Button = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 11px 16px;
  background: ${props => props};
  align-self: flex-start;
`;

export const ButtonComponent: FC<ButtonComponentProps> = props => (
  <Button onPress={props.onPress}>{props.title}</Button>
);
```

```
// styled.d.ts file
import 'styled-components/native';
import { MainThemeInterface } from './theme.model';

// and extend them!
declare module 'styled-components' {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
  export interface DefaultTheme extends MainThemeInterface {}
}
```

```
// theme.model.ts file
export MainThemeInterface {
   mode: string;
}
```

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

<s>I downgraded to `"styled-components": "^3.4.9"` and typings start to work. Seems like issue exist in the version `^5.0.0`.</s>

**UPDATE 2**

Issue was inside project set-up. After re-creating project with `expo cli` issue disappeared.

Comment: Have you tried passing the props interface to the Button's style object? `const Button = styled.TouchableOpacity<ButtonComponentProps>`

Comment: @Emma yes, and it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Could you post a fiddle or codesandbox.io with your code?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Tried to replace

```
declare module 'styled-components' {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
  export interface DefaultTheme extends MainThemeInterface {}
}
```

by

```
declare module 'styled-components/native' {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
  export interface DefaultTheme extends MainThemeInterface {}
}
```

The problem persists. I was not able to implement Theming for react-native using styled-components and typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on my comment..you could try passing the props interface to the Button's style object like so

```
const Button = styled.TouchableOpacity<ButtonComponentProps>`
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 11px 16px;
  background: ${props => props};
  align-self: flex-start;
`;
```

Or

```
const Button = styled.TouchableOpacity<{ mode: string }>`
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 11px 16px;
  background: ${props => props};
  align-self: flex-start;
`;
```